# Get iframe id within cross-origin iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, cross-domain

Is it possible to get iframe id within cross-origin iframe?

The html of iframe:

```
<iframe height="100%" width="100%" scrolling="yes" allowtransparency="true" id="vfFrameId_1544771685610" name="vfFrameId_1544771685610" allowfullscreen="true" force-aloha-page_aloha-page="" allow="geolocation *; microphone *; camera *"></iframe>
```

I tried:

- `window.frameElement`, it returns `null`. So I can't use `window.frameElement.id` to get the id.

Is there any other solution?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy

Comment: The only way is to use `window.postMessage` in iframe, and handle the message in page, get the frame id, then post it back?

Comment: If you've control over the cross-origin iframe, then post-messaging is probably the best [choice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy). If you haven't control over the cross-origin iframe, then there's nothing you can do. The question is, what would you do with the id, you can't get the id without a reference to the iframe, and when you have it, getting its id is more or less useless ..?